# Unable to fetch value of web element even though it exists

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to fetch the Text of All table rows in a web page using Selenium C#.
Below is the code for retriving all tr's from the web page:

```
  var trElements = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
```

This shows the data correctly. For example, tr element number 35 has text 'canara bank' in it, that can be seen in below image.

[image]

Now I am trying to extract only text of all the tr elements. Either by using LINQ or by using for loop:

```
string[] strrr=      trElements.Select(t => t.Text).ToArray();
```

Surprisingly, Text property of most of the element does not show up the data that was shown in web element. Randomly data of some elements keeps showing up or goes off.

[image]

I want to ensure that data of web elements is correctly converted to string array. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are 3 possibilities.

1. The rows are not visible. So element.Text can't give you the text. In this case, you need to use `element.GetAttribute("innerText")` instead of `element.Text`.

```
string[] strrr = trElements.Select(t => t.GetAttribute("innerText")).ToArray();
```

2. The script does not have enough wait time. In this case, you just need to add wait to check text length.

```
var trElements = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
List<string> strrr = new List<string>(); 
foreach (var tr in trElements)
{
    IWait<IWebElement> wait = new DefaultWait<IWebElement>(tr);
    wait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    try
    {
        wait.Until(element => element.Text.Trim().Length > 1);
        strrr.Add(element.Text.Trim());
    }
    catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
    {
        strrr.Add("");
    }
}
```

3. The text will be displayed when you scroll down.

```
int SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 1;
int SCROLL_LENGTH = 500;
var jsExecutor = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
int pageHeight = Int32.Parse((string)jsExecutor.ExecuteScript("return document.body.scrollHeight"));
int scrollPosition = 0;
while (scrollPosition < pageHeight)
{
    scrollPosition = scrollPosition + SCROLL_LENGTH;
    jsExecutor.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, " + scrollPosition + ");");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME);
}
var trElements = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
```

Comment: Best part I liked is your depth of research and presenting all possibilities. God bless you.